# what does "value" represent in d3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

What does `value` do in the example of a [force-directed graph made with d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this block of code from the example you gave:

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });
```

You can see that the `value` attribute in the JSON file is used to set the `stroke-width` of the line that connects that node to its target node.

Specifically this part of the function:

```
.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
```

Comment: i was about to answer the same, 7 minutes later... value is an attribute of link that can be used to change link behavior driven by code.